# Get all elements of List without iteration scala

Tags: scala, list, apache-spark, rdd

I am working in spark I have to create an RDD[(Double, Double)] from elements of List

I have

```
val list1: List[Double] = List(16.0,5.0)
```

When I do

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize (Seq(list1))
```

I get an RDD of type `RDD[List[Double]]`
But I want an RDD of type `RDD[(Double, Double)]` that I can achieve by doing:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize (Seq((16.0,5.0)))
```

So basically, how can I inside `Seq()` list all the elements of my list without iterating and do something like that:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize (Seq((list1(*))))
```

Comment: I'm confused. What is your expected output in this case? `RDD[(16.0, 5.0)]` What happens if you have `3, 4, or n` elements?

Comment: `(Seq((16.0,5.0)))` is not a `Seq` containing a `List`. It's a `Seq` of tuples (Tuple2 in this case).

Comment: Here's another question with my detailed usage of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502410/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-requirement-failed-columns-not-found-in-dou

Answer (score 0):

All you want to do is to convert `List[Double]` to `RDD[(Double, Double)]` pairwise you might go with:

```
sc.paralelize(
    list.sliding(2, 2)
        .filter(_.size == 2)
        .map(tup => (tup.head, tup.last))
)
```

You might alternatively use `.grouped(2)` instead of `.sliding(2, 2)` as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: If this is what OP actually wants, then `grouped(2)` is probably better than `sliding(2,2)`

Comment: @SergGr not sure if there is any difference apart from being several characters shorter -> under the hood it's the same `GroupedIterator`

Comment: What if my List contains more than two elements? (which is my case) And I want to have an RDD[(Double, Double, Double)]? What is the alternative for `tup.head, tup.last`

Comment: @greenshade, I believe `grouped` is better because it better conveys the intention of the developer. @AhlAhl, you may use access by index such as `list.grouped(3).filter(_.size == 3).map(seq => (seq(0), seq(1), seq(2))`.

Comment: That is in case I know before execution the size of my list, but what if I don't know it and want to get all elements of my list that is my question, for example I can have a list with 3 elements and when I execute again it is 4 elements, so that doing `(seq(0), seq(1), seq(2)` doesn't help

Comment: @AhlAhl, 1. if you don't know the number of values, you can't but them into a tuple because `Tuple1`, `Tuple2`, `Tuple3` ... are all different types in Scala. Moreover they go only up to `Tuple22`. The more important question is why you want to put them in a tuple? Could you update your question with an example of your intended usage of a such `rdd`?

Comment: I prefered to open another question, here's the post with my detailed intended usage : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48502410/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-requirement-failed-columns-not-found-in-dou