# Java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Columns not found in Double

Tags: scala, csv, cassandra, rdd, spark-cassandra-connector

I am working in spark I have many csv files that contain lines, a line looks like that:

```
2017,16,16,51,1,1,4,-79.6,-101.90,-98.900
```

It can contain more or less fields, depends on the csv file

Each file corresponds to a cassandra table, where I need to insert all the lines the file contains so what I basically do is get the line, split its elements and put them in a List[Double]

```
sc.stop
import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf


val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val nameTable = "artport"
val ligne = "20171,16,165481,51,1,1,4,-79.6000,-101.7000,-98.9000"
val linetoinsert : List[String] = ligne.split(",").toList
var ainserer : Array[Double] = new Array[Double](linetoinsert.length)
for (l <- 0 to linetoinsert.length)yield {ainserer(l) = linetoinsert(l).toDouble}
val liste = ainserer.toList
val rdd = sc.parallelize(liste)
rdd.saveToCassandra("db", nameTable) //db is the name of my keyspace in cassandra
```

When I run my code I get this error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Columns not found in Double: [collecttime, sbnid, enodebid, rackid, shelfid, slotid, channelid, c373910000, c373910001, c373910002]
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.mapper.DefaultColumnMapper.columnMapForWriting(DefaultColumnMapper.scala:108)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.MappedToGettableDataConverter$$anon$1.<init>(MappedToGettableDataConverter.scala:37)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.MappedToGettableDataConverter$.apply(MappedToGettableDataConverter.scala:28)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter.<init>(DefaultRowWriter.scala:17)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter$$anon$1.rowWriter(DefaultRowWriter.scala:31)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.DefaultRowWriter$$anon$1.rowWriter(DefaultRowWriter.scala:29)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.writer.TableWriter$.apply(TableWriter.scala:382)
  at com.datastax.spark.connector.RDDFunctions.saveToCassandra(RDDFunctions.scala:35)
  ... 60 elided
```

I figured out that the insertion works if my RDD was of type :

```
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double, Double)]
```

But the one I get from what I am doing is RDD `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double]`

I can't use scala Tuple9 for example because I don't know the number of elements my list is going to contain before execution, this solution also doesn't fit my problem because sometimes I have more than 100 columns in my csv and tuple stops at Tuple22

Thanks for your help

Comment: Ahl, it probably would help if you provide more details (such as stack trace) for your "IllegalArgumentException requirement failed"

Comment: @SergGr I just added it

Comment: Ahl, unless I'm mistaken in Cassandra each Table still has a Schema with [known Columns](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cql/ddl.html#column-definition). So how come that you don't know beforehand how many columns there will be in the CSV-file/the target table?

Comment: I don't know before hand because I have many tables that have different schemas, and many csv files, and each csv file has to be inserted in the corresponding table, I don't have one table only

Comment: Ahl, if you don't know the target table and CSV schema beforehand, how from the logical point of view you know proper mapping between the fields in CSV and the table columns?

Comment: The saveToCassandra function inserts in order of arrival the parameters you give it if you don't precise the columns of the table, it assumes that you gave the right order and inserts your parameters in the order they were given, exmaple I have a table person (id, name, age) if I insert an rdd that contains (1, john, 3 ) it assumes that 1 is for is, john for name, and 3 for age and does insertion

Answer (score 1):

As @SergGr mentioned Cassandra table has a schema with known columns. So you need to map your `Array` to `Cassandra schema` before saving to Cassandra database. You can use `Case Class` for this. Try the following code, I assume each column in `Cassandra` table is of type `Double`.

```
//create a case class equivalent to your Cassandra table
case class Schema(collecttime: Double,
                  sbnid: Double,
                  enodebid: Double,
                  rackid: Double,
                  shelfid: Double,
                  slotid: Double,
                  channelid: Double,
                  c373910000: Double,
                  c373910001: Double,
                  c373910002: Double)
object test {

  import com.datastax.spark.connector._, org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkContext._, org.apache.spark.SparkConf

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "localhost")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val nameTable = "artport"
    val ligne = "20171,16,165481,51,1,1,4,-79.6000,-101.7000,-98.9000"
    //parse ligne string Schema case class
    val schema = parseString(ligne)
    //get RDD[Schema]
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(schema))
    //now you can save this RDD to cassandra
    rdd.saveToCassandra("db", nameTable)
    }


    //function to parse string to Schema case class
    def parseString(s: String): Schema = {
       //get each field from string array
       val Array(collecttime, sbnid, enodebid, rackid, shelfid, slotid,
       channelid, c373910000, c373910001, c373910002, _*) = s.split(",").map(_.toDouble)

       //map those fields to Schema class
       Schema(collecttime,
         sbnid,
         enodebid,
         rackid,
         shelfid,
         slotid,
         channelid,
         c373910000,
         c373910001,
         c373910002)
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works in case I had only one table to work with, but in my code I have many cassandra tables who have different schemas

Comment: Can't you create similar schema for all your tables and then insert data into cassandra? For your 100 column problem you can use StructType instead of case classes in scala.